# Rails server broken after Action Cable and using rails restart command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Going through the following book with the error showing: Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1, iteration F5: Broadcasting with Action Cable. As far as I am concerned I followed the directions precisely, my only possible flaw was to type: rails restart rather than rails server again, now it will just not boot anymore! Any possible help is appreciated!

**Error in Question:**

> /Users/dj911ice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in method_missing: undefined method action_cable_ for # (NoMethodError)

The server error:

[image: Server Error]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo around line 57 of `config/environments/development.rb`, where you are calling `config.action_cable_` instead of `config.action_cable`.

Remove the trailing underscore and restart your rails server.